# Collapsible sections in outlook 2007?

Tags: html, outlook-2007, office-2007

Is it possible to create html with collapsible sections in outlook 2007? I've done some research and learned that secure email client will not allow execution of script. Before I give the idea up, I want to run it through the experts here!

Comment: Jeremy is right - no scripts allowed. Not even on Gmail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run any kind of scripts in most email clients.

For a helpful reference, check out this page from Campaign Monitor:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

As you can see outlook2007/2010 is pretty awful. It doesn't support most things you'd think would be pretty standard, like background images and other simple things like that.

Stick with tables and inline styles and you'll be ok.

Comment: disappointing the way outlook is...but i appreciate the great link. thanks!